# Why is isa field of Objective C object has 1 offset with its class pointer?

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers, struct, objective-c-runtime

I'm trying to using the following code to understand NSObject's C struct layout. First I print its struct layout using NSData, then I print the class pointer directly using `[NSObject class]`.

```
id obj = [NSObject new];
long nsSize = class_getInstanceSize([NSObject class]);
NSData *nsData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(__bridge const void *)obj length:nsSize];
NSLog(@"obj: %@", nsData);
NSLog(@"NSObject Class: %p", [NSObject class]);
```

And I got the result:

```
2015-10-15 08:11:53.913 ObjC_CMD[11406:1999149] obj: <f1e06573 ffff1d00>
2015-10-15 08:11:53.913 ObjC_CMD[11406:1999149] NSObject Class: 0x7fff7365e0f0
```

What's interesting is the end of class pointer is **e0f0**, while the `NSData` print result shows its isa as **eof1** (it's in reverse order because of little endian). I read in book that the isa pointer is topmost in an object's struct layout, so why it has **1 offset**?

By the way, I have also tried on other types of objects, there is always **1 offset** between isa and class pointer. Shouldn't they be the same?

P.S. 
I just noticed that the class pointer begins with 0x7fff, but the isa in C struct seems to be 0xffff, this difference is also interesting. What's the exact relationship between isa field and class pointer obtained from `[NSObject class]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The 1 in the least significant bit means `isa` is not a pointer](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2013/09/24/objc_explain_Non-pointer_isa.html). In 64-bit land, [the 64-bits of `isa` got repurposed](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH3-SW30) into a bit-mask. On the most significant side of the `isa` bit-mask are other bit fields and the reference count.

Part of the `isa` bit-mask (30 bits in the middle) identify the class object, which is the part you recognized.